# How to fetch Player record from table in sql?

Tags: sql

I have Three tables as,

Player Table,

```
- id
- name
- team_id
```

Team Table:

```
- id
- image
- tournament_id
```

Tournaments Table:

```
- id
- name
```

and **I want to fetch count of employee appearing in Tournaments.** Thanks

Comment: Write a query that returns the data you want. You did not specify a question in your...question. What have you tried and how isn't it working? Without knowing the relationships between these tables, anything we offer would be only guessing. Please read the Stack Overflow FAQ on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to fetch count of employee appearing in Tournaments.

This can be achieved using `JOIN` and `group by` as follows:

```
select t.id, t.name, count(*)
  from tournaments t
  join team tm on t.id = tm.tournament_id
  join player p on p.team_id = tm.id
 group by t.id, t.name
```